# What is the name of the Long class in Kotlin JNI?

Tags: java, c, kotlin, java-native-interface

This Kotlin function

```
 @JvmStatic external fun registerNativeWindowFromSurface(): Integer;
```

is found by with return type `java/lang/Integer` but when I add a Long:

```
 @JvmStatic external fun registerNativeWindowFromSurface(id: Long): Integer;
```

I cannot find it with `java/lang/Long` in the argument.

Is Kotlin's Long a java `long` or a `java/lang/Long`? How can I get a Long class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integer` is not the Kotlin-native integer type. `Integer` is an alias to `java.lang.Integer`. `Int` is the Kotlin integer type.

```
@JvmStatic external fun registerNativeWindowFromSurface(): Int
@JvmStatic external fun registerNativeWindowFromSurface(id: Long): Int
```

These will compile to functions with signatures

```
int registerNativeWindowFromSurface();
int registerNativeWindowFromSurface(long id);
```

And the class instance for the primitive type `int` is [`java.lang.Integer.TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE). Likewise for `long` and [`java.lang.Long.TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#TYPE).

If you actually *intend* to use Java boxed types, you can reference them with their fully qualified names.

```
@JvmStatic external fun registerNativeWindowFromSurface(): java.lang.Integer
@JvmStatic external fun registerNativeWindowFromSurface(id: java.lang.Long): java.lang.Integer
```